# Limit number of Expression Engine Channels

Tags: channel-entries, ee3

I have heard that some say that you should limit the number of expression engine channels you use to about three regardless if you use the free or paid version. Has anyone else experience EE giving problems after you create more than three channels?

Comment: I think core limits you to about 3 channels, but that's only because it's for limited personal use. If you need something more, you pay for a license. That's not to say that you should only limit yourself to 3 as that's not practical at all for most production sites. stuartmcd69's answer sums it up pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea where you heard that tip as it's simply not true.

I've worked on sites with upwards of 15 channels without issue.

Granted, the more channels you have the more fields you will have which may bloat the db but performance isn't really affected.

Maybe their point was give good thought to your channel/field setups to avoid duplication of content storage.

Comment: More channels does not add more fields unless you are also adding additional field groups, no?  In my understanding it's field groups that add bloat.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the websites having more than 30 channels without any issue. But according to your point you should take care while creating Channel fields. The channel field's name should not repetitive. Because that causes the duplication of content.

Answer (score 0):

One of my websites currently has 26 channels. I needed to be able to use the same entry title for multiple entries so I made multiple channels to act as data containers.  In this way, I can use channel entry tags or SQL queries to grab the channel quickly and do what I need to do with the data.

I also assign the same field group to several channels to keep the number of custom fields in use as low as possible. I believe that this is the more critical part as adding fields will quickly bloat your DB.

Answer (score 0):

My average site has around 8 channels. Biggest site has 20.

Channels are generally analogous to database tables, if you're familiar with databases.

Best thing to do is familiarize yourself with channel preferences, categories, field groups, statuses, member access, and the channel:entries tag. After using those things in a few cases you'll get a better idea for good/bad use of channels.